# ASP.Net 3.5 web app trying to load System.Web.Mobile.dll version 4.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, mobile, binding, version

I'm trying to debug a web application that I inherited from a previous developer, it was written using Visual Studio 2008 with the .Net 3.5 framework (hence using asp.net 2.0).  I can see temporary asp.net files show up in the 2.0 folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files)

Unfortunately every time I try browse to the login page on my local IIS server I get the following error:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

The assembly is not referenced anywhere in the application, I have no idea why it's trying to load it when I browse to the page. I tried explicitly referencing the the 3.5 version as follows in the web.config using the 2.0 framework dll:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.Mobile.dll

No matter what I do however it seems to try to bind to the 4.0.0.0 version and fails to load the page.